# Why did Vice President Bush hide when a reporter asked this question?

Tags: united-states, political-history

The movie "American Made (2017)" is related to the history of the American  government.

> REPORTER: Vice President Bush, did you know about the Contra aid or not, sir?

Snapshot is real and taken from *American Made (2017)* movie:

[image]

Context: Ronald Reagan is the President.

Why did Vice President Bush hide when the reporter asked this question?

Comment: Please provide source information for this photo, date of  the referenced news conference.

Comment: @justCal I added source information

Comment: So your image is a 'real' snapshot of a *scene in a movie*?  By source I mean is the image from, for instance a publicity site for the movie, so the legal rights to show this image on this site can be confirmed? (especially since this is a movie currently in theaters).(Possibly covered in [this discussion](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3569/is-using-a-copyright-image-in-a-question-considered-fair-use))?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Likely Because George H W Bush wanted to run for President and he hadn’t yet figured out how he was going to obfuscate the fact that [he had been a vocal and powerful voice in favor of the policy](https://www.salon.com/2011/11/25/the_iran_contra_scandal_25_years_later/) and he would eventually allow the blame to fall on the people he had convinced to join him.(*) Bush would say he was “[out of the loop](https://www.washingtonpost.com/archive/politics/1992/09/24/bush-out-of-the-loop-on-iran-contra/4ee467ab-8531-46e5-8da5-ff7bd97a6609/?utm_term=.a0eca21cc95b)” or literally out of the room when it was discussed, due to drinking too much ice tea that day.

The [Tower Commission](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_Commission) (John Tower) would find George H W Bush innocent of all involvement in Iran-Contra.  [Senator Tower would be offered the Secretary of Defense job](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Tower#Post-senate_career) in the Bush administration but would fail to be confirmed by his colleges in the senate, after several military women came forward and detailed several drunken gropings by the senator while chairman of the armed forces committee and visiting military bases.

(*) This sentiment that Bush had been an early supporter and had convinced others to join him were also given in the book "Destiny and Power".

[Bush would go on as President to pardon 6 Iran-Contra decision makers](https://www.brown.edu/Research/Understanding_the_Iran_Contra_Affair/thepardons.php) on Christmas Eve, who by all rights could have included himself.

1. **Elliott Abrams**, a former assistant secretary of state for Central America
2. National Security Adviser **Robert McFarlane**.
3. CIA official **Duane Clarridge**.
4. CIA official **Alan Fiers**.
5. CIA official **Clair George**
6. former Secretary of Defense **Caspar Weinberger**.

[LA Times Headline](http://articles.latimes.com/1992-12-25/news/mn-2472_1_iran-contra-affair)

> **Bush Pardons Weinberger, 5 Others in Iran-Contra; Act Called Cover-Up : Inquiry: Prosecutor accuses President of misconduct, claims Bush kept own notes of arms-for-hostages affair. Christmas Eve clemency scuttles six-year investigation.**

Comment: "_I am pretty sure that the reporter had reviewed a variety of documents_" - I am afraid your trust in journalistic integrity is misplaced.

Comment: I wrote the original post from memory. As I sourced it I did discover a few errors.. Secretary of Defense, not state.. 6 pardon's not 5. As for the rest it is common knowledge and not be confused with supposition.

Comment: I can't quite understand your basic thesis.  From what I remember, most if not all of the people who would vote for Bush would have approved of aid to the Contras.

Comment: I don't have a thesis.  Nor an agenda.  Just recounting the facts and interpreting the question.

Comment: And regardless of whether people "agreed with it or not",   It was against the law, and their was a special prosecutor working for two years to get to the bottom of it.  The administration can't sell military equipment to generate  a slush fund, so they can create their own budget unapproved by congress.   The special prosecutor as well as the presidential commission missed the most basic facts that bush would later freely admit.

Comment: @ JMS: Use whatever word you like, it still remains that you present a hypothesis/intrepretation to explain why Bush said & did various things, which seems to me unlikely.

Comment: @jamesqf wasn’t that the point of the question?

Comment: Thank you for addressing the request for sources. Previous comment removed.  @sds Heh, I am trying to be charitable in re the WaPo reporter.

Comment: @jamesqf please read George H W Bush’s autobiography where he freely confirms what others have previously stated.  That Bush was a thought leader on the Iran contra strategy which was illegal and to protect his presidential run he obfuscated his knowledge of and leadership role.  He then both offered his SEC defense role to the head of the senate investigation and pardoned the six officials found guilty of involvement in the criminal act.